# Git pushed old email and name settings

Tags: git, git-config, git-credential-winstore

Month ago I installed my new company computer (with git-for-windows) and pushed some changes to one project. I don't have any idea where git got my personal email and name but it had this information about me in --global and pushed it that way.

I thought I fixed it as I changed my personal data in git config for `git config --global`. On other locations it is not set (--system, --local, --file) .

```
> git config --global -l
user.email={my}.{name}@{company}.cz
user.name={My Name}
```

which is correct and in folder of the project I pushed (user.name/email)

```
> git config -l
...
credential.helper=manager
user.email={my}.{name}@{company}.cz
user.name={My Name}...
```

it is also correct, but somehow it still pushed my old email and name. I also add `credential.helper` as I think it could be of some importance, but I haven't set windows credentials (and therefore they are empty).

My past commits will stay this way but I would like to fix my future commits.

Comment: Can you make sure your local git config was not modified? Just open the  `<repo>/.git/config` file and find `[user]` section's email/name.

Comment: Yes sir, I checked and I confirm nothing has changed. There is no user section.